# ASP .Net Mixed Mode Authentication - Forms and Shibboleth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, shibboleth, mixed

We have an existing ASP .Net application which uses forms authentication. A client has requested to integrate with their active directory and a consultant has suggested that we use Shibboleth as the service provider.

We still want to keep forms authentication for other clients but also be able to support federated authentication.

I found this  post  regarding  authentication with Shibboleth but lost on how to integrate this one with our current  forms authentication - our application is not yet MVC.

[asp.net MVC authentication with Shibboleth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718012/asp-net-mvc-authentication-with-shibboleth)

My question is : how dow we convert our application to authenticate  with  shibboleth  but still  retain  our forms based authentication ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that your client supports Shibboleth.  Shibboleth requires that your client is operating an Identity provider.

Comment: The client currently uses ADFS.  The reason why Shibboleth was considered as an option was cost and being able to integrate with any identity provider.